# Machine learning for lighting direction estimation from pictures?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision

Newcomer to machine learning and stackoverflow.

Recently, I have been trying to create a machine learning algorithm that estimates the direction of a light source based on the reflection of an object.
I know this may be a complicated subject and that's why, as a first step, i tried to simplify it as much as possible.

I first changed my problem from a regression problem to a classification problem by only taking as output : Light source is on left side of object or Light source is on the right side of the object.
I am also only making one angle vary for my dataset.

Short version of my question :

- Do you think that it is possible to do such thing with machine learning ? (my experience is too limited to really be sure)
- If yes, what would be the more suited neural network for you ? CNN ? R-CNN? LSTM ? SVM ?
- What would be the pipeline to complete this task ?

I am currently using Unity Engine with directional light that takes a random X angle between [10,60] / [120,170] and a sphere with metallic reflection to create and label a dataset. Here is an example :

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqe1v.jpg Label : 0 (Left side)
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OUAX.jpg Label : 1 (Right side)

For the pre-processing :

- Images are resized to a 64x64 image
- Transformed from RGB to grayscale format.

For the machine learning, i'm currently using tensorflow and a convolutional neural network with :

- 10000 Balanced, labeled data of 64x64 grayscale pictures as input and 0/1 as Label
- 3 Convolutional Layers with filter [16,32,64] with size [5,5] RELU
- 3 Pooling Layers with size [2,2] and stride [2,2]
- 1 Dense layer with 1024 Hidden neurons and dropout (Rate = 0.4) RELU
- 1 Dense Layer with 2 output neurons (1 for each class) Softmax

As for the issue : My network is simply not learning the loss hardly goes down and accuracy show that good result are random, whatever the data, the number of layer, optimizer, learning rate, ... My output just average between the two classes : [0.5 , 0.5].

My guess is that the problem is more complicated than i first thought, that my data doesn't give a good hint of what my prediction should be and that I should rather train a network that detects the reflection dot on an object and then use the orientation between the center of object and the dot. Am I right ?

Another guess is that the convolutional layer doesn't take position into account, so for the convolution part, all the images are the same since the sphere is always the same, as well as the lighting pattern. It will always detect the same thing and won't take into account that the light region has moved. Do you have any advice on which network I could use to resolve this issue ?

I'm really looking for some advice, warning on how to tackle this kind of task.
Please remember that I am still pretty new to machine learning and still learning more than my machines hehe...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you think that it is possible to do such thing with machine learning ?

Absolutely. And you've correctly chosen a CNN model - it's the best suited for this task.

> My guess is that the problem is more complicated than i first thought, that my data doesn't give a good hint of what my prediction should be and that I should rather train a network that detects the reflection dot on an object and then use the orientation between the center of object and the dot. Am I right ?

No, CNN has proven to classify pretty well from the raw pixels. It should figure out itself what to pay attention to.

> Do you have any advice on which network I could use to resolve this issue ?

I would be great if you provide your full code. There are so many reasons for not learning: image pre-processing bugs, data mislabeling, poor choice of hyperparameters (learning rate, initialization, ...), wrong loss function, etc. There can be *simply bugs*.

What I suggest right away, based on described CNN architecture:

- `5x5` filter size is probably too large, since you don't have that many filters. Try `3x3` and increase the number of filters a bit, e.g. `32 - 64 - 64`.
- I assume that you use `CONV - POLL - CONV - POLL - CONV - POOL`, not `CONV - CONV - CONV - POOL - POOL - POLL`. Just to make sure.
- You probably don't need so many neurons in your FC layer. You have just two classes and pretty similar images! Reduce `1024` to say `256`.
- You don't experience any overfitting at the moment, so disable the dropout for now: `keep_probability=1.0`.
- Pay attention to initialization and learning rate. Try different values in log-scale, e.g. `learning_rate = 0.1, 0.01, 0.001` and check if learning pattern ever changes.

Comment: Thank you very much @Maxim for your help, data mislabeling was the issue (see my answer ... ), i feel very dumb about it but heh thats how you learn hehe. Also thank you for your tips, it helped me refine my network. Good luck and see you

Comment: @MarcRavaine Great! Don't feel bad about this bug, it happens with every engineer, especially when the API is new and unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Maxim for his answer. It was very helpful and helped me solve my problem as well as refining my network.

He pointed me out to the problem : Data Mislabeling.

I was pretty sure about my data labeling but verified anyway.

The problem was there...

I write the answer here so it can maybe help other unaware tensorflow users : 
When you use **tf.string_input_producer** without specifying it, the default is : "**Shuffle = True**" which shuffles your filenames queue.

Since i use a .csv file for the labels and .png folder for the images, the labels where read in order from 1 to 10000 whereas the .png files were read randomly.

I feel very dumb about it, but that's how you learn hehe.